# How do I set the TERM environment variable for the Gnome Terminal Emulator app?

Tags: gnome-terminal

The TERM environment variable defaults to xterm so the .bashrc file does not provide full color in the shell by default.

How to I change the TERM environment variable to xterm-color for the gnome terminal emulator app only?

Update: By full color I mean changes the command prompt to use color in addition to displaying output such as directory listing in color too.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not Provide full color"? How many colors do you have in your terminal? How did you tested it?

Comment: .bashrc changes the PS1 prompt to color only if XTERM=xterm-color

Comment: What is the output of `tput colors`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### For `gnome-terminal`

Edit the profile settings in `gnome-termninal`:

[image]

Replace `/bin/bash` with your shell command and use your parameter for `TERM`.

You can also edit the entries with `dconf`. Open a terminal and start `dconf-editor`:

```
dconf-editor
```

Open the entry `org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:` and select your profile. Change the value for `custom-command`.

Comment: Having edited the profile setting using the screenshot, the terminal emulator app opens and closes and I'm not able to use it at all.

Comment: The terminal closes again when you've made a bad record. For example, the wrong shell. Give me a second.

Comment: I have improved  my answer, read the `dconf-editor` part.

Comment: Thanks.  I finally found it under org.gnome.terminal.legacy.profile.*

Comment: The second method using the .pam_environment didn't have any effect but I corrected a typo in the GUI box and now it appears to have taken effect upon launching the app.  I will +1 your answer when I get enough reputation points. Thank you.

Comment: I have removed the second part. If the first method is good for you, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓).

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation.  I will come back to it when I've earned some reputation points on here.

Comment: Not an upvote, use the gray ✓. For that you don't need 15 reputaion. For that you get two.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: You have enough reputations ;)

Answer (score 10):

There are two issues here.

One is how to detect if you're running inside gnome-terminal (or any other app using the same vte widget for the current terminal emulation). Assuming you're on a recent enough Ubuntu, the presence of the `$VTE_VERSION` variable tells you this. You could edit your `.bashrc` to contain something like

```sh
if [ -n "$VTE_VERSION" ]; then
    # Gnome-terminal and other vte3-based emulators
    color_prompt=yes
fi
```

The other issue is that for some reason Ubuntu's default `.bashrc` tries to look for `xterm-color` which is not really used nowadays. Either the standard `xterm` (which supports colors anyways), or the more modern `xterm-256color` are the popular choices, the default slowly moving towards the latter. (gnome-terminal changed its default from `xterm` to `xterm-256color` in 3.16, which is present in Ubuntu 15.10 beyond)

If you would like to move forward and already enjoy plenty of colors in several applications, I recommend that you already switch to `TERM=xterm-256color`, which you could also do in the if-branch above.

Ubuntu's `.bashrc` is obsolete for using `xterm-color`. I much rather recommend modifying these bits in the script around whatever `$TERM` you already have (`xterm`) or would prefer to have (maybe `xterm-256color`), rather than the other way around, modifying `$TERM` to match `.bashrc`'s requirement.

Comment: Aware of `xterm-color` being outdated, I still think it’s a good idea to append `-256color` to `$TERM`, making the capability more explicit.